# Eliminar Tabs de forma dinámica

Tags: flutter

Buenas noches y como es costumbre gracias por el tiempo que se toman en ayudarme.

He estado trabajando en una ruta de una aplicación Flutter. Esta consta de una vista de Tabs, con sus respecivas TabBarViews, usando TabBar. Actualmente, al presionar el FloatingActionButton(FAB) agrego más tabs a mi TabBar, y hasta ahí todo bien!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi dolor de cabeza es el siguiente:**
Agregué un 2do FAB con el que **deseo eliminar el Tab que esté actualmente activo en mi pantalla.** Logré que elimine el último Tab creado, pero ese no es el resultado que busco :(

Me dispuse a buscar información, y pensé en la posibilidad de utilizar la propiedad `key` del `DefaultTabController` que estoy usando, pues pienso que quizá tenga una propiedad que me permite conocer cuál es el Tab que está actualmente activo, para identificarlo de alguna forma entre todos los demás y así poder eliminarlo. Lo digo porque un uso similar le di al `Key` de un widget `Form`

¿Hay alguna forma de identificar a un Tab de entre todos los demás de mi TabBar? Agradeceré mucho su ayuda. Les dejaré una captura de lo que tengo actualmente

Comment: Deberías agregar el código que usaste para poder ayudarte en base a eso. Pero la respuesta sería sencilla.
Puedes guardar un entero con el indice del tab que tienes activo, los tabs los agregas en un array, tendrías que crear un tabcontroller para escuchar en que tab te encuentras actualmente, entonces con eso ya tienes el current index. 
Cuando presionas el botón eliminar, solo eliminas del array en base al indice que tienes y refrescas todo.

Comment: @diegoveloper muchas gracias! Sí funcionó. tuve algunos problemas al inicio porque no me percaté de que la propiedad length era `final`. y estaba definiendo el controller dentro del `initState()` por lo que su longitud permanecía en 1. Terminé colocando la definición dentro del `build()` para que la propiedad se actualice cada que actualizo la longitud de mi lista de tabs.
De nuevo, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Dale, no hay problema. Te invito a mi canal: www.youtube.com/diegoveloper